# What card game are the gang playing in the hotel in "Rivals and Arrivals"?

Tags: dragon-ball

The players appear to pick cards from each other hands, hoping to match them together and stick the other players with the joker. Apparently if you're stuck with the joker you lose.

What game is this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the card game is *Old Maid*.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_maid_(card_game)